# Sort by AVG(rating)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mySQL-query that sorts by first **suburb** and then **AVG(rating_table.rating)**.

Here is the **street_table**:

```
id       street_name       suburb

0        streetone         subone
1        streettwo         subthree
2        streetthree       subthree
3        streetfour        subtwo
```

And here is the **rating_table**:

```
street_id    rating

1            1
2            1
3            4
2            2
1            3
```

And this is the result I am looking for:

```
id      suburb         avarage_rating

0       subone         (no rating)
1       subtwo         1 + 3 / 2 = 2
3       subthree       4 / 1 = 4 (Just one vote..)
2       subthree       2 + 1 / 2 = 1.5
```

(As you can see, **#3** is before **#2** because of the **avarage_rating**)

Comment: Could you show the results of your effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `join` with aggregation.  However, you need a `left join` to be sure that you keep all rows where there is no rating:

```
select s.id as street_id, s.suburb, avg(r.rating) as rating
from street_table s left join
     rating_table r
     on s.id = r.street_id
group by s.id, s.suburb
order by s.suburb, avg(r.rating) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the ORDER BY to use multiple columns like:

```
SELECT .... ORDER BY suburb, AVG(rating_table.rating);
```

You can define order specific to items too

```
SELECT .... ORDER BY suburb ASC, AVG(rating_table.rating) DESC;
```